# Domain Redirect To Subfolder

Tags: redirect, ip

I have a site that redirects from `www.domain.com` to `www.domain.com/sub`

I have two domains pointing at this address. One is hosted by Go Daddy, and when that one is hit it shows a "Loading [Site Name]...your browser should automatically redirect you within a few seconds..." message, but when I hit it from the other I get no message and the redirect just happens. What is going on here? I would like to think that Go Daddy is the culprit and shows that on redirects, but how would it get the project name in the explain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually somewhere in the code. It is unclear why one domain provider caused the page to show up and one didn't.